# Can I add delegates to abstract class?

Tags: c#, delegates, abstract-class

I know that I can't add delegate to interfaces in c# but can I add delegate to abstract class? Is it possible?

Comment: Delegates are a feature that is largely obsolete. Do you need an `Event` or an `Action`? Both should be possible in both interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: It contradicts comments to answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is syntactically correct but makes little sense. You still should tell us what you really want/need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

```
public abstract class TestClass
{
    public delegate void TestAction(string s);
}
```

then yes you can.

Comment: But can I add delegate to interfaces?

Comment: @roman-v1 you write _I know that I can't add delegate to interfaces_ and yet you ask _can I add delegate to interfaces_? Mhmm :\

Comment: Yes, write it, but now I'm not sure in it.

Comment: No you can't add them to an interface. (Error 'TestAction': interfaces cannot declare types) PS: it's easy to test, just open visual studio

Comment: @roman-v1 - And note that error: `TestAction` is a _nested Type_, there is no semantic difference with a definition outside `TestClass`.

Comment: how about abstract delegate ?